# Chrome notification not showing with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I'm trying to have my Tampermonkey script show a Chrome notification, but no notification is showing up. I have allowed notifications on the site.

Here is my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        somewebsite.com/*
// @grant        GM_notification
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function ($, undefined) {
    $(function () {
        GM_notification({title: 'foo', image: 'bar', text: '42', onclick: console.log});
    });
})(window.jQuery.noConflict(true));
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the `GM_notification` documentation](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_notification), GM_notification's `image` parameter requires an image.
**`'bar'` is not an image, so the GM_notification call fails (silently).**

Granted, it would be nice if there was an error message, but currently Tampermonkey does not provide one. (Feel free to file a bug report.)

Also:

- Those `(function` wraps are completely unnecessary, and just clutter/complication.
- Ditto the `window.jQuery.noConflict` -- when `@grant none` is not in effect.
- No parameter is passed to the `onclick` callback so giving it `console.log` has no effect.

Here is **a complete working script** with the above errors corrected:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Notification test
// @match       *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @match       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769201/*
// @grant       GM_notification
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

GM_notification ( {title: 'foo', text: '42'} );
```

With a valid image:

```
GM_notification ( {
    title: 'foo', text: '42', image: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/geLPT.png'
} );
```

With a useful `onclick`:

```
GM_notification ( {
    title: 'foo', text: '42', image: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/geLPT.png',
    onclick: () => {
            console.log ("My notice was clicked.");
            window.focus ();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Another example for 1sec timeout: `GM_notification ( {title: 'foo', text: '42', timeout: 1000} );`

Answer (score 2):

These tips help, but for me the additional step required was to enable Chrome notification permissions in the Mac